What is the distribution of US federal government income from the main kinds of taxes?
I've been trying to figure out how different kinds of taxes weigh into the US federal tax income overall. But the online resources I find seem to describe more opaque categories, e.g.
https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/americas-finance-guide/government-revenue/
Where we have "individual incomes taxes", "corporate income taxes" etc. And - I want to see, for example, how much the Capital Gains Tax accounts for.

The capital gains tax is just one part of the overall income tax system, so it isn't readily segregated and there aren't obvious categories. There is no separate capital gains tax. The vast majority of U.S. government revenue is from the income tax and payroll taxes, with minor contributions from gift and estate and generation skipping transfer taxes, from excise taxes, from tariffs, from profits on making currency, from returns on government owned assets, and from fines and penalties. Payroll tax is mostly FICA (mostly Social Security with some Medicare in addition) with a little FUTA.

We do not have: "individual incomes taxes" or "corporate income taxes".  We have one huge complicated income tax that different sorts of taxed entities pay. "Tax expenditures" (i.e. policy driven tax breaks and  their revenue costs) are regularly itemized, however, and can provide some insight. https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/tax-policy/tax-expenditures

@ohwilleke: The fact that taxes are paid all at once as an aggregate doesn't mean that you don't have an "income tax" or "capital gains tax" or "whatever tax"...

The connection are much deeper than that. Your capital gains impact the tax you pay on your ordinary income, for example. There are probably tables of different sources of taxable income by type (e.g. rent, qualified and non-qualified dividends, royalties, self-employment, salaries, wages, interest, etc.) but we don't say that there is a "rent tax" or an "interest tax". Passthrough taxation further muddies the waters as the person who pays it and earns it aren't always the same. See https://www.irs.gov/statistics/soi-tax-stats-statistics-of-income

I would expect that the GAO or CBO has breakdowns of these different types of taxes, since Congress needs it when making changes to the tax laws. E.g. if they're considering changing the CG tax rates, it helps to know how this will affect the total tax revenue.

@Barmar: CBO = Congressional Budget Office; GAO = Govt. Accountability Office?

@einpoklum Yes, those are the two offices that provide input to the budgeting process.

@Barmar The Treasury Department and the Joint Taxation Committees of the U.S. House and U.S. Senate respectively also publish statistical analysis of tax laws, as do various think tanks and non-profits.
